# old() value of checkbox, with the one from the database, along with if old remains empty laravel

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-8

I want to submit a checkbox with an update. I am using this code, and it's working fine. The problem is that the second parameter you give the old() function is used when the first value is null. So when you do old('amenities', $propertyAmenityArr) and no old value for 'amenities' is found, $propertyAmenityArr is used. So I want it to be written so that the codes work even if there is no old value for 'amenities', which means it should remain unchecked. I figured out three possibilities for it

If old() has the value, it should be checked.
if $propertyAmenityArr has the value, it should get checked
if the checkbox is unchecked, it should remain unchecked

```
<div class="form-row">
    <?php
    $amenityMo = \App\Models\Amenity::orderBy('amenity_name', 'ASC')->get();
    $amenity = $amenityMo->split($amenityMo->count() / 1);
    ?>
    @foreach($amenity as $row)
        <div class="col-md-2 mb-2">
            @foreach($row as $j => $amenityCl)
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $amenityCl->id; }}" name="amenities[]"
                           @checked(in_array($amenityCl->id, old('amenities', $propertyAmenityArr)))  id="defaultCheck{{ $amenityCl->id; }}">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck{{ $amenityCl->id; }}">
                        {{ $amenityCl->amenity_name; }}
                    </label>
                </div>
                    <?php $j++; ?>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
    @if($errors->has('amenities'))
        <div class="error text-danger fs-6">{{ $errors->first('amenities') }}</div>
    @endif
</div>
```

The issue is that if any of the checkboxes remain unchecked, I get null while dumping old values, which is fine, but the database values are getting checked, but they shouldn't as we have checked nothing; old contains two parameters, if one is null the other one gets executed, I want to make sure that if old value is null, no checkbox shall remain checked.

Comment: Check if the form was submitted before using $propertyAmenityArr as the default value. You can use the request()->isMethod('post') function to check if the form was submitted. If it was, use old('amenities') only, otherwise use old('amenities', $propertyAmenityArr)

Comment: @KarlHill nope the problem i mentioned only happens when, the page is first time loaded it is taking the database value okay fine, when I am checking the checkboxes and in my second time old values are getting updated okay fine, but what if I dont chose any checkboxes then old values becomes null, so at that time i want to show my checkboxes to be unchecked